# In Laravel how do I check if user is logged in from a package?

Tags: php, laravel, composer-php

I am trying to create a reusable Blog package. Here are my package routes:

```
Route::group(['middleware' => ['auth']], function () {
    $path = 'MyPackages\Blog\Controllers';

    Route::resources([
        'blog' => "{$path}\BlogController",
        'post' => "{$path}\PostController",
        'comment' => "{$path}\CommentController",
        'tag' => "{$path}\TagController"
    ]);
});
```

Which I am registering in my `ServiceProvider` boot()

```
$this->loadRoutesFrom(__DIR__.'/routes/web.php');
```

In my controller:

```
<?php namespace MyPackages\Blog\Controllers;

use App\Http\Controllers\Controller;
use Illuminate\Http\Request;
use MyPackages\Blog\Models\Tag;

class TagController extends Controller
{
    public function __construct()
    {
        parent::__construct();
    }

    public function index(Tag $tag)
    {
        $posts = $tag->posts;

        return view('blog::post.index', compact('posts'));
    }
}
```

My Parent `__construct()` looks like this:

```
public function __construct()
{
    $this->middleware('auth');
}
```

But I keep getting redirected to the home page.

In my `routes/web.php` main routes file, I simply have a bunch of route definitions and a call to `Auth::routes();`

How can I stop it from redirecting me to the home page?

I recognize that the BlogController will need to be moved out of auth but everything else will have auth protection.

Any help?

Comment: Just take the parent::_construct(); out of your constructor for your blogs controller add your middle ware at method level in blogs controller for the methods you want to protect

Comment: You already have `['middleware' => ['auth']`, so there is no need to check again in the `__construct()`